# how to combine 2 different table?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

how to combine 2 different tables where they contain the same fields but different data, example
Cash_Expenses

```
{
exp_date
exp_cat_id
exp_amount
exp_remark
}
```

Cheque_Espenses

```
{
exp_date
exp_cat_id
exp_cheque_NO
exp_amount
exp_remark
}
```

exp_cat

```
{
cat_id
Cat_name
}
```

now what i am trying to do is that i want to combine those three and sum the amount to its respective cat, where when i use this sql statment

```
SELECT DISTINCT exp_cat.cat_name, Sum(exp_cash.exp_amount) AS SumOfexp_amount, Sum(exp_cheque.exp_amount) AS SumOfexp_amount1
FROM (exp_cat INNER JOIN exp_cheque ON exp_cat.ID = exp_cheque.exp_cat_id) LEFT JOIN exp_cash ON exp_cat.ID = exp_cash.exp_cat_id
GROUP BY exp_cat.cat_name;
```

i get duplications where the sum is incorrect, any suggestion i well be glad to learn for anyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you close:

```
select cat_name, sum(exp.exp_amount)
from (select exp_cat_id, exp_amount from cash_expenses
      union all
      select exp_cat_id, exp_amount from cheque_expenses) as exp
inner join exp_cat on exp.cat_id = exp_cat.cat_id
group by cat_name;
```

Comment: the data in cash_expenses and cheque_expenses shouldn't overlap, so UNION ALL would be more efficient (although this is MS Access, so possibly doing the sum on a pocket calculator would be more efficient)

Comment: @YellowFog - this is a site for objectivity, not product bashing. Access is more than capable for small database projects not involving simultaneous users.

Comment: @BenV i wanted to ask you, what if i want to split each amount on its receptive table, example 
when the i run the query, the amount is split into two fields one for cheque and other for cash is it possilbe or not

Comment: @John there is a distinction between sarcasm and product bashing

Comment: @edosoft how would a reader not knowing much about databases realise the difference? Sarcasm is _very_ difficult to put in writing especially for readers in a different country, so when giving a serious answer it's dangerous to add a sarcastic comment

Comment: @John: I would think most people would question the seriousness of comparing a pocket calculator to a database.  Personally I appreciate a little humor.  But I do understand the concern.

Comment: @BenV from experience, using sarcasm to people who don't share your culture or language very often goes wrong. Even if you use smilies :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a UNION query:

```
SELECT * FROM Cash_Expenses
UNION
SELECT * FROM Cheque_Expenses;
```